# Отключить ограничение на количество символов в теге script

Tags: битрикс

Есть сайт на bitrix, написанный задолго до меня. На сайте не отображаются кнопки "Изменить" и "Удалить" у элементов. Проблема в том, что тег script, в котором прописаны эти все кнопки, выводит только 10000 символов и ставит "…" в конце. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Куда выводит? Тег скрипт не отвечает за вывод. Проверьте не засунут ли этот код в функцию обрезки вывода. Если да, то перенесите его оттуда. Сам по себе тег script вообще ничего выводить не может.

Comment: @NikolajSarry, script появляется при включении режима правки, в нём условие window.BX и функции BX.CMenuOpener и BX.admin.setComponentBorder. Тег ни где явно не прописан.